# Which programming language do I need to use in order to create a program that interacts with "inspect element"?

Tags: google-chrome, element, inspect

I want to create a program that when I launch it, it automatically edits 2 elements of a web page.

I want the program to:

1. Enter "inspect element" on a certain website.
2. Edit two elements of the website, which are " data-status="show" "
   and " data-paywall-overlay- 
       status="show" ", changing the values from "show" to "hide".
3. Repeat the process every time the user enters a website.

My question is: Which programming language do I need to learn to create this program. I have zero experience in programming.

Sorry if I didn't make myself clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript would be that language. But there is no need for you to program that, since it has been programmed already as a script for Greasemonkey/Violentmonkey. Still, feel free to have a look at the following script, if the goal is to learn.

The script can be found here: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/18585-newspaper-paywall-bypasser/discussions/16022

It is likely that you will find the comments useful as well.